# Resize image keeping aspect ratio and fit in bounds nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

I need to resize images to fit in a specific dimensions. I want to keep aspect ratio.

For example

```
original image:
w:634
h:975

resize to max:
w:50
h:100

result:
w:50
h:85
```

I have not found anything that could do that(calculations for w and h)
and I am too dumb to figure it out by myself

copilot suggested me something that just keeps aspect ratio

If you want to use packages. I prefer jimp for image editing.

Comment: your original image and your result have different aspect ratios ...  ie  `975/634 ~ 1.54` but `85/50 ~ 1.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the aspect ratio of your original image and of your maximum dimensions. According to that ratios, either take the maximum width or height as fixed and calculate the other side accordingly.

```
let 
  oheight = 634, owidth = 975,
  mheight = 50, mwidth = 100,
  theight, twidth;


let 
   oratio = owidth/oheight, // (~1.54)
   mratio = mwidth/mheight, // (2)
   

if (mratio > oratio) {
  //original image is "higher" so take the maximum height
  //and calculate the width accordingly
  theight = mheight;  //50
  twidth = theight * oratio; //77
} else {
  //original image is "wider" so take the maximum width
  //and calculate the height accordingly
  twidth = mwidth;
  theight = twidth / oratio;
}
```

But any decent image processing library will have the functionality, that you can pass in the maximum dimensions and define to keep the aspect ratio and will do these calculations internally ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Jimp.read('image.jpg')
  .then((lenna) => {
  const isHorizontal = lenna.getWidth() > lenna.getHeight();
  const ratio = isHorizontal
      ? lenna.getWidth() / lenna.getHeight()
      : lenna.getHeight() / lenna.getWidth();
  const width = 375; // set the width you want
  const height = isHorizontal ? width / ratio : width * ratio;

  return lenna.resize(width, height).quality(60).write("image.jpg");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: That won't work because it doesn't respect the maximum size of the image that it can be

Comment: Try it now. Check if the image is horizontal or vertical and use this value to calculate the aspect ratio. and height.